# Why keeps my Virtual Machine sending ARP messages in internal network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wireshark, arp

Following setup:

Windows 10 host system runs 2 Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machines from VirtualBox. Both the VMs have their network adapter set to "internal" mode, which means only an internal network can be set up. Now I assigned static IP addresses to the VMs, disabling DHCP. Both the VMs run in the same local network.

When I use one VM to ping the other one (which works perfectly) and I keep it pinging for e.g. 2 minutes, Wireshark shows me ARP request/replies between both of the VMs.
**But not only at the beginning of the communication** (which would make perfectly sense) **but also in between.** The time between the ARP messages differs from 5 seconds to also 20 seconds.

Also I checked how long the ARP table is cached via `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_stale_time`  and I got `60` seconds as a result. But still the ARP requests are send way more often.

Does anyone has an explanation for that?

[Wireshark screenshot showing multiple ARP request/replies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Wrv.png)

[Another screenshot of the same communication record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkl67.png)

Comment: If the VM has two network interfaces, could there be a problem of [ARP Flux](https://netbeez.net/blog/avoiding-arp-flux-in-multi-interface-linux-hosts/)?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your comment. I don't think that ARP Flux is the problem. The second network interface is in VirtualBox's "NAT-Mode" to communicate to the rest of the world via the host. Nevertheless I tried both the command line arguments that are mentioned in your linked article. But still the ARP messages occured during pinging the other VM. (I also deactivated the "NAT-Mode" interface in the Ubuntu settings). So I don't think that it has anything to do with that?